# PHP get array values having a specific word

Tags: php, arrays

Consider an array like this,

```
$sports = array('Football','cricket ball','tennis ball','shuttle bat','hockey stick');
```

I want to create an array from $sports like this,

```
$ball = array('Football','cricket ball','tennis ball');
```

based on the search key(***here it is 'ball'***).

If am looping through the array **$sports** and checking one by one, will get the result. But then am already inside a loop and that may be even loops more than 50,000 times. So thought of avoiding another loop.

Is there any other way to get this done?

Thanks

Comment: [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter) + [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match)

Comment: here I don't know which key user will be searching. So how can I define a callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter) + [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match) functions:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array  = array('Football','cricket ball','tennis ball','shuttle bat','hockey stick');

$word   = 'ball';

$results    = array_filter(
    $array,
    function($value) use ($word){
        return preg_match('/' . $word . '/i', $value);
    }
);

print_r($results);
?>
```

Shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Football
    [1] => cricket ball
    [2] => tennis ball
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sports = array('Football','cricket ball','tennis ball','shuttle bat','hockey stick');
$input  = 'ball';
$result = array_filter($sports, function ($item) use ($input) {
    if (stripos($item, $input) !== false) {
        return $item;
    }
});
print_r($result);
```